# Looping a html5 video set number of times

Tags: html5-video, video.js

How could we do this using video.js My initial thoughts are we can trigger play when the video ends.

pseudo code

```
    for (int i = number_of_times_to_loop, i>=0, i--) {
        see if the timer of the video reached the end {
            trigger play from start
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play the video on the ended event to loop. Then it's just a matter of tracking how many times you have played it already.

```
var max = 3,
  i = 1;

videojs("home_video").on('ended', function(event) {
  if (i < max) {
    this.play();
    i++;
  }
});
```

Comment: `ended` event does not fire when looping with [`loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-loop) attribute.